# How to map correctly JSON from angular 5 POST call to a java entity using resteasy?

Tags: angular, rest, resteasy

I have the following code from the angular 5 component:

```
export class TripsComponent implements OnInit {
...
...
addTrip() {    
    let newTrip = new Trip(this.new_trip_name,
    this.new_trip_description, this.company);
    this.tripService.addTrip(newTrip).toPromise();
  }
//The company object is initialize inside ngOnInit()
```

The trip service look like this:

```
 addTrip(tripTemp: Trip): Observable<any> {
     let tripObj = {
       trip: tripTemp
     };
    console.log('Adding trip ' + JSON.stringify(tripObj));
    return this.http.post(`${this.baseUrl}/Trips/Trip`, JSON.stringify(tripObj), httpOptions);
  }
```

The java rest api look like this:

```
@POST
@Path("Trip")
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response addTrip(Trip trip) {    
        tripDao.addTrip(trip);
        return Response.ok().entity("Trip added successfully").build();
}
```

The company object inside the trip is annotated as XmlTransit (not sure if that's causing a problem):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = false)
@XmlTransient
    public Company getCompany() {
        return this.company;
    }
```

The problem is that the company object is coming as NULL and it is require
field to save the Trip object. Any idea how to allow automatic transformation
for this inner object ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the @XmlTransient.